# JQuery binding click event on richfaces datascroller

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a richfaces datatable with a datascroller. Which I want is binding an "onclick" event on datascroll buttons. The purpose of this operation is to color the rows based on some criterias defined in the javascript on each page change action through the datascroller.

Below is my JQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#paketler a').live('click', function() {
        stopajRenklendir();
    });
});
```

and my datatable simplified:

```
                    <rich:dataTable rendered="#{not empty sigortaFaturaPaketiSorgulamaBean.paketProvizyonListModel}" rows="2" 
                    value="#{sigortaFaturaPaketiSorgulamaBean.paketProvizyonListModel}" var="item" border="1" cellspacing="3"
                    styleClass="teminatTablosu" headerClass="teminatTablosuHeader" footerClass="teminatTablosuFooter" rowKeyVar="idx"
                    id="paketler">
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputText
                            value="Paket Sayısı: #{sigortaFaturaPaketiSorgulamaBean.paketProvizyonListModel.rowCount == -1 ? 0 : sigortaFaturaPaketiSorgulamaBean.paketProvizyonListModel.rowCount  }"
                            style="float:left" />
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="pagingWrapper">
                        <rich:dataScroller fastStep="2" page="#{sigortaFaturaPaketiSorgulamaBean.page}" maxPages="2" id="paging" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                </rich:dataTable>
```

The script works as intended, coloring the rows I want, but after coloring the table is rendered again, which makes the process useless.

Comment: Side note, `live` is deprecated, use `$('#paketler a').on('click', function()...`

Comment: I still haven't found any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "oncomplete" of rich:dataScroller :

```
    <rich:dataScroller oncomplete="stopajRenklendir();" ... />
```

If you want to call an action or render another component, you can use a4j:jsFunction in oncomplete of rich:dataScroller :

```
    <rich:dataScroller oncomplete="myJavascript()" ... />

    <a4j:jsFunction name="myJavascript" render="paketler" action="#{sigortaFaturaPaketiSorgulamaBean.myAction}" ... />
```